# Azure Function Bindings for Service Bus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---c-example) to create a trigger for a service bus queue.

I'd like to be able to access the message properties.  I thought I could simply add `Dictionary<string, object> properties` to the parameter list like so:

```
public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "connectionSetting")]
        // Message message,
        string myQueueItem,
        Int32 deliveryCount,
        DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
        string messageId,
        string ContentType,
        Dictionary<string,object> properties,
        TraceWriter log)
```

But that throws:

> Error indexing method 'Program.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'properties' to type Dictionary`2. Make sure the
>   parameter Type is supported by the binding.

Here is [a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata) of the possible parameter bindings.  What am I getting wrong?

Update:

I tried changing the singature to

```
public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "connectionSetting")]
        // Message message,
        string myQueueItem,
        Int32 deliveryCount,
        DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
        string messageId,
        string ContentType,
        IDictionary<string, object> properties,
        TraceWriter log)
```

It produces the same error:

> Error indexing method 'Program.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'properties' to type IDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For function v2 runtime, the name of the parameter has changed to `UserProperties`

To fix the error, update the parameter to the following:

```
IDictionary<string, object> UserProperties
```

Here is the related code from Service Bus extension.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/42a711763ddecca9df4caae9c7dc5fe16178880c/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Triggers/ServiceBusTriggerBinding.cs#L127

Answer (score 0):

```
IDictionary<string, object> properties
```

**Update:**

for version 2 use the following bindings:

```
public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, Connection = "connectionSetting")]
        Message message,
        string label,
        Int32 deliveryCount,       
        DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,  
        string messageId,
        string ContentType, 
        ILogger log)
    {           
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
        var userProperties = message.UserProperties;
    }
```

Comment: I have looked my function (V1), it's working well for all binding arguments

Comment: Ah, mine is V2 - possibly a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is, see for instance the following link: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/819

Comment: how do we add UserProperties with `MessageSender` ?